# Problems printing validations messages in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, razor

> I have encountered a problem when it comes to printing validation of
>   input fields in a View.
>
> I have a view where I want the user to fill in a form. In this form I
>   need to validate the input before the user can proceed. In my dbModel
>   I have set different rules on how I want the code to be validated. In
>   the view I've tried to show the error messages using
>   Html.Validationsummary(true)
>
> It worked perfectly fine on an earlier project. But not on this one...
>
> Here is the DbModel class

```
 public class Kjop
        {
            [Key]
            public int ordreid { get; set; }
            public int kundeid { get; set; }
            public int produktid { get; set; }
            public DateTime tid { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fornavn må oppgis")]
            [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Maks 50 bokstaver")]
            [DisplayName("Fornavn")]
            public string fornavn { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Etternavn må oppgis")]
            [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Maks 50 bokstaver")]
            [DisplayName("Etternavn")]
            public string etternavn { get; set; }

            [RegularExpression("^[a-z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9]+)*\\.([a-z]{2,4})$", ErrorMessage = "Ugylding formatering på epost")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "feil i epost")]
            [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Maks 50 bokstaver")]
            [DisplayName("Epost")]
            public string epost { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telefon må oppgis")]
            [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{8}", ErrorMessage = "8 tegn i telefonnr")]
            [DisplayName("Telefon")]
            public string telefon { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Adresse må oppgis")]
            [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Maks 50 bokstaver")]
            [DisplayName("Adresse")]
            public string adresse { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postnr må oppgis")]
            [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{4}")]
            [DisplayName("Postnummer")]
            public string postnr { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Poststed må oppgis")]
            [DisplayName("Poststed")]
            public string poststed { get; set; }

            public bool betalt { get; set; }
            public int antall { get; set; }
        }
```

> The variable names is in Norwegian, never mind that. The code is still
>   the same in any language :)
>
> My Controller

```
public ActionResult Registrering()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

        public ActionResult Registrering(FormCollection innKunde)
        {
                try
                {
                    using (var dbB = new databaseContext())
                    {
                        using (var dbP = new produktContext())
                        {
                            var produktId = from d in dbP.Produkter
                                            where d.ProduktNavn.Equals(GlobalVariables.valgtProdukt)
                                            select d;
                            int produktid = 0;


                            foreach (var b in produktId)
                            {
                                produktid = b.ProduktID;
                            }


                            var nyttKjop = new Kjop()
                            {
                                kundeid = 0,
                                produktid = produktid,
                                fornavn = innKunde["Fornavn"],
                                etternavn = innKunde["Etternavn"],
                                antall = Convert.ToInt32(GlobalVariables.produktAntall),
                                tid = DateTime.Now,
                                epost = innKunde["Epost"],
                                telefon = innKunde["Telefon"],
                                adresse = innKunde["Adresse"],
                                postnr = innKunde["Postnr"],
                                poststed = innKunde["Poststed"],
                            };
                            dbB.Kjoper.Add(nyttKjop);
                            dbB.SaveChanges();
                            Response.Write("Data lagt inn");
                            Session["Nykunde"] = nyttKjop;


                            //Adde sessions på variabler til kvitteringsiden
                            return RedirectToAction("Kredittkort");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception feil)
                {
                    Response.Write(feil);
                    return View(); 
                }


        }
```

> And the View

```
@model Nettbutikk_v1.Models.Kjop

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Registrering</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Kjop</legend>


            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fornavn)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fornavn)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fornavn)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.etternavn)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.etternavn)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.etternavn)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.epost)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.epost)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.epost)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.telefon)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.telefon)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.telefon)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.adresse)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.adresse)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.adresse)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.postnr)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.postnr)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.postnr)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.poststed)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.poststed)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.poststed)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Registrer" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

> I am getting the following Exception when I try to parse something...

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

> Can anybody help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yo create a new block try-catch DbEntityValidationException:

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException exDbEntityValidationException)
```

EXAMPLE:

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException exDbEntityValidationException)
{
   DbEntityValidationException exval = exDbEntityValidationException;

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   foreach (var excep in exval.EntityValidationErrors)
   {
       sb.AppendFormat("YourField: {0} {1}",((YourEntityType)excep.Entry.Entity).YourField, Environment.NewLine);

       excep.ValidationErrors.ToList().ForEach(v => sb.AppendFormat("   Field: {0} -  {1}{2}", v.PropertyName, v.ErrorMessage, Environment.NewLine));
   }

      System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(sb.ToString());
}
```